# How often does the oozie coordinator check for the presence of files in Synchronous Datasets?

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator

```
<coordinator-app name=""
  frequency="1 17 * * *"
  start="${start_date}" end="${end_date}" timezone="Asia/Seoul"
  xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.2"
  >
  <controls>
    <timeout>1440</timeout>
    <execution>FIFO</execution>
  </controls>
  <datasets>
    <dataset name="file" frequency="${coord:days(1)}"
             initial-instance="${start_date}" timezone="Asia/Seoul">
      <uri-template>some_uri</uri-template>
      <done-flag></done-flag>
    </dataset>
  </datasets>
</coordinator-app>
```

I have an oozie coordinator like the one above.
I know that the Coodinator runs every day at 17:01.
And I understand that it checks whether the dataset exists for 24 hours (1440 minutes).

`<dataset name="FILE1" frequency="${coord:days(1)}" ..>`
Here's where I'm confused.
Does frequency mean checking whether data exists in the uri every day?

According to the documentation, frequency is the expected cycle of new data generation.
So how often does the coordinator check whether a data set has been created?
In other words, I'm curious what the polling cycle is.

Is it just detecting as soon as there is data for 1440 minutes before time out?

I apologize for not being familiar with English.

I just have the code, so I haven't experimented with it.